# large geojson validation issue

Tags: json, validation, geojson

In my project I'm using http://geojsonlint.com/ for geojson validation

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://geojsonlint.com/validate',
    type: 'POST',
    data: some_geojson,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: processSuccess,
    error: processError
});
```

everything would be alright if it could handle large files like [this one](http://vmgeoserver.vd.dk/geoserver/VD/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=VD:TEMA_MARIUS_EQA&cql_filter=EQUIPMENTTYPE='Tavlestander'&outputFormat=JSON&srsName=EPSG:4326) for example

My questions are the following:

Are there any other ways to validate geojson offline or online?

Can I just validate geojson as usual JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you do not implement your custom validator based on the [GeoJSONLint](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojsonlint.com) source code? then you could validate your JSON offline.

Take a look at the [Utils](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojsonlint.com/blob/master/geojsonlint/utils.py) class.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know python
Or you mean rewrite it to javascript?

Comment: Yep, you can rewrite it using JS, or if you are using a Java servlet container like Apache tomcat you can do it using Java.

Comment: Look at geojsonhint, https://github.com/mapbox/geojsonhint, its a JS validaton for GeoJSON.